# Ruby 1.9.1-p234, Passenger 2.2.5, Rails 2.3-stable closed stream on POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, ruby-1.9

I've setup Ruby 1.9.1 (p234) on a Ubuntu server. I'm trying to deploy a Rails app which vendors Rails 2.3-stable on Apache 2.2/Passenger 2.2.5.

GET requests work fine, POST requests break immediately with the following log entry:

`` Processing UsersController#new (for 80.203.77.44 at 2009-10-24 20:54:55) [GET]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"new"}
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering users/new
Completed in 23ms (View: 20, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://myapp/user/new]
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  2009-10-24 20:55:01 +0200
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  closed stream
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/rewindable_input.rb:86:in make_rewindable'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/rewindable_input.rb:26:inread'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/request.rb:136:in POST'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:incall'
    /var/www/myapp/app/releases/20091021213913/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in call'
    /var/www/myapp/app/releases/20091021213913/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:incall'
    /var/www/myapp/app/releases/20091021213913/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:inblock in call'
    :8:in synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:incall'
    /var/www/myapp/app/releases/20091021213913/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:95:inprocess_request'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in main_loop'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:378:instart_request_handler'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:336:in block in handle_spawn_application'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:183:insafe_fork'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:334:in `handle_spawn_application' ``

...and then some.

I've read up, and found this: http://blog.labnotes.org/2009/09/01/ruby-1-9-1-p234passenger-2-2-5-tempfile-rb-fix/ which points to a patch that removes a single line from Ruby 1.9.1-p234's tempfile.rb. Unfortunately for me, inspecting that file I find that the offensive line has already been removed. So that leaves me a bit clueless, as my problem persists. Any ideas?

Comment: fixed in latest passenger, ugly hacks no longer required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is a workaround in passenger 2.2.8 so this is no longer needed.**

Casual Jim's response above worked for me. Thanks very much Jim for your help.

The diffs on my system are, respectively, as follows. I hope this is helpful.

Killian.

```
*** /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb.orig Tue Nov  3 17:43:30 2009
--- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  Tue Nov  3 17:43:46 2009
***************
*** 31,36 ****
--- 31,37 ----
  require 'etc'
  require 'fcntl'
  require 'tempfile'
+ require 'stringio'
  require 'phusion_passenger/exceptions'
  if !defined?(RUBY_ENGINE) || RUBY_ENGINE == "ruby"
    require 'phusion_passenger/native_support'


*** /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb.orig  Tue Nov  3 17:44:34 2009
--- /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb   Tue Nov  3 17:45:55 2009
***************
*** 137,143 ****
      # keep this order for thread safeness
      begin
        if File.exist?(@tmpname)
!         closed? or close
          File.unlink(@tmpname)
        end
        @@cleanlist.delete(@tmpname)
--- 137,143 ----
      # keep this order for thread safeness
      begin
        if File.exist?(@tmpname)
!         # closed? or close
          File.unlink(@tmpname)
        end
        @@cleanlist.delete(@tmpname)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks alot for posting that! I've been confusing that magic "line 140" with another tempfile fix (described here: http://blog.labnotes.org/2009/09/01/ruby-1-9-1-p234passenger-2-2-5-tempfile-rb-fix/) and tried to fix the wrong thing. It works now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the following to make it work

gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
add require 'stringio' to that file on line 34

open lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb
comment out line 140

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in. However, I'm still not getting anywhere. Would you mind posting your tempfile? I cannot understand how my tempfile looks different from other people using the same version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Damien. I had the same problem and whilst i havent got an exact answer/link for you from memory i had to patch rack and *not* tempfile. I hope this helps

Comment: Exactly how did you patch Rack? I noticed that Passenger vendors a pre-1.0.0 version of Rack. I tried to replace the vendored version with Rack 1.0.1, but keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Casual Jim's fix worked for me, thanks, this problem was driving me nuts.

I also had to patch actionview (per hector gomez's patch at https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2188-i18n-fails-with-multibyte-strings-in-ruby-19-similar-to-2038) to get rails and ruby 1.9.1 working.

Comment: I'm running Rails 2-3-stable from git, it works without patching.

Answer (score 0):

When applying this fix, I cannot restart the Passenger module more than a few time using the tmp/restart.txt method. After that, requests are accepted but never served. I suspect that the patch may be leaking tempfiles